# $n^{n^{n^n}} \equiv n^{n^n} \pmod{9}$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $n$ be a positive integer and suppose that $\gcd(3,n) = 1$. Prove that $$n^{n^{n^n}} \equiv n^{n^n} \pmod{9}$$ if and only if $$n^{n^n} \equiv n^n \pmod{\phi(9)}.$$

I was wondering how we can drop the exponent like that because of the phi. Is there a good reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

- Thanks to [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), we know
  $$
  n^{n^n} \equiv n^{n} \pmod{\phi(9)} \quad \Rightarrow \quad n^{n^{n^n}} \equiv n^{n^n} \pmod{9}
  $$
- For the other direction, remember $\phi(9)=6$. It is clear that
  $$
  n^{n^n} \equiv n^{n} \pmod{2}
  $$
  and since ${n^n} \equiv n \pmod{2}$ we also have
  $$
  n^{n^n} \equiv n^{n} \pmod{3}
  $$
  Hence
  $$
  n^{n^n} \equiv n^{n} \pmod{6}
  $$